# PhoneGap/Cordova invalid date

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm build an android app with PhoneGap. This is the code

```
    getReadableDate: function(date_){
        var date, datevalues;
        console.log('Date input:' + date_);
        date = new Date(date_);
        console.log('Date value:' + date);
        datevalues = [date.getFullYear(),
                ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
                ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
                date.getHours()
             ];
        return datevalues[2] + '/' + datevalues[1] + '/' + datevalues[0] + ' @ ' + datevalues[3] + ':00';
    },
```

That's is what I view in the console:

[image]

Any ideas?

In Firefox works correctly but on mobile android apk not. (Version 2.2 android)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this with cordova.

```
var date = new Date("2013-02-14T18:00:00");
console.log(date);
console.log(date.getDay());
```

It returns a valid date object. It may be that your date_ is an object and not an actual string value. Try converting it to a string and see what you get. Like so.

```
   date = new Date(String(date_));
```

Comment: It's a string. If I put manually "2013-02-14T18:00:00":
http://gyazo.com/eb14bec40edd182f5f30ad798fea9649.png?1360865686

Same error.

Comment: Code:
`
  getReadableDate: function(date_){
            var date, datevalues;
            date = new Date("2013-02-14T18:00:00");
            console.log(date);
            datevalues = [date.getFullYear(),
                    ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
                    ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
                    date.getHours()
                 ];
            return datevalues[2] + '/' + datevalues[1] + '/' + datevalues[0] + ' @ ' + datevalues[3] + ':00';
        },
`

Comment: It may be a browser shim that jquery it taking care of. Do you have jquery included?

Comment: What is your version of android that you're testing on? I ran it on 4.2

Comment: eheh no, I'm running on android 2.2! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here testing on a device with android 2.3.6.

This is my solution:

```
// input = "2013-04-26T10:07:20.123Z"
function strToDate(input) {
  var dateStr = input.substring(0, 10);
  var dateParts = dateStr.split('-');
  var timeStr = input.substring(11, 19);
  var timeParts = timeStr.split(':');
  var result = new Date(Date.UTC(dateParts[0], dateParts[1]-1,
      dateParts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]));
  return result;
}
```

dateParts[1]-1 as months index begins with 0.

hth

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using this awesome lib: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using and Android 2.2. I had same problem (using on 2.2) and I solved it by using an AVD with an Android 4.1.

It's not really a solution but I must conclude that it's not working on Android 2.2...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is convert it to string. I am not sure why it must be like this, but it works with:

```
var newDate = String(new Date());

var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
contact.id = "123";
contact.birthday = newDate;

contact.save(function(params) {
    console.log(params);
}, function(params) {
    console.log(params)
});
```